# How do I set "Configuration" options for "npm pack" commands?

Tags: node.js, npm

Doc page https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-pack has very useful configuration options.  Right now I want to use config "pack-destination" per https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-pack#pack-destination, but they give no invocation examples and no hint about how to make these settings.

I have tried setting "pack-destination" in my active npmrc file, via command-line switch "--pack-destination=dirpath" (with both relative and absolute paths), argument "pack-destination=dirpath".  The first two have no effect.  Last seems to be how you set some tags.

Comment: I also struggled with this for couple of hours. But I found a work around you achieve the same. Navigate to the folder where you want create the package(.tgz file) and run npm pack there. eg. `cd destination/to/create/package && npm pack path/to/package.json/directory`

Comment: Both variants "--pack-destination=dirpath" and "--pack-destination dirpath" are working for me today.  No idea why it wasn't working for me on the 20th.  If I were specifying an invalid target directory, I would have gotten an error message about that and it would not have written to current directory.

Comment: Seriously -- why do the docs not explain how to use the options??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure how exactly did you invoked the command-line, but I just used like this in my terminal with success:

```
npm pack --pack-destination="./dest"
```

relative path worked just fine

Comment: It didn't work for me. It ignores the flag and path completely.

Comment: @manjeetlama this only works for npm >= 7